# Valgrind reporting memory leaks when using API

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm building an application with the Dyninst API, and with a simple Hello World application have many many memory leaks.  Dyninst is managing its own memory, in part, and I'm curious if Valgrind would report that memory as "leaked".

I'm using C++ and an not 100% comfortable with it quite yet, so if I forgot to include any information that would be helpful, please say so.

Thanks!

http://www.dyninst.org/

---

Here is the Hello World application:

```
#include "BPatch.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  BPatch bpatch;
}
```

---

Valgrind Output:

```
==10307== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
==10307== Copyright (C) 2002-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10307== Using LibVEX rev 1884, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==10307== Copyright (C) 2004-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==10307== Using valgrind-3.4.1-Debian, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.
==10307== Copyright (C) 2000-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10307== For more details, rerun with: -v
==10307== 
==10307== 
==10307== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 31 from 1)
==10307== malloc/free: in use at exit: 16,021 bytes in 422 blocks.
==10307== malloc/free: 2,198 allocs, 1,776 frees, 74,304 bytes allocated.
==10307== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==10307== searching for pointers to 422 not-freed blocks.
==10307== checked 8,642,848 bytes.
==10307== 
==10307== 44 (12 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 51 of 95
==10307==    at 0x40269EE: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:224)
==10307==    by 0x46505EF: Dyninst::SymtabAPI::typeCollection::getAllTypes() (Collections.C:515)
==10307==    by 0x46223F6: Dyninst::SymtabAPI::Symtab::getAllstdTypes() (Symtab.C:2182)
==10307==    by 0x435E510: BPatch::BPatch() (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x804914B: main (mutator.c:14)
==10307== 
==10307== 
==10307== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 52 of 95
==10307==    at 0x40269EE: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:224)
==10307==    by 0x438C3C4: BPatch_type::BPatch_type(Dyninst::SymtabAPI::Type*) (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x435E54F: BPatch::BPatch() (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x804914B: main (mutator.c:14)
==10307== 
==10307== 
==10307== 266 (72 direct, 194 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 69 of 95
==10307==    at 0x40269EE: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:224)
==10307==    by 0x438B6D7: BPatch_type::BPatch_type(char const*, int, BPatch_dataClass) (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x438BCAA: BPatch_type::createFake(char const*) (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x435E4DB: BPatch::BPatch() (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x804914B: main (mutator.c:14)
==10307== 
==10307== 
==10307== 1,412 bytes in 60 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 82 of 95
==10307==    at 0x40269EE: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:224)
==10307==    by 0x4817AD3: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.10)
==10307==    by 0x4818734: (within /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.10)
==10307==    by 0x48188A5: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.10)
==10307==    by 0x4665707: global constructors keyed to annotations.C (annotations.C:38)
==10307==    by 0x4666E3C: (within ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libsymtabAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x45A85AF: (within ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libsymtabAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x400E343: (within /lib/ld-2.9.so)
==10307==    by 0x400E473: (within /lib/ld-2.9.so)
==10307==    by 0x400084E: (within /lib/ld-2.9.so)
==10307== 
==10307== 
==10307== 3,657 (72 direct, 3,585 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 84 of 95
==10307==    at 0x40269EE: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:224)
==10307==    by 0x435E583: BPatch::BPatch() (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x804914B: main (mutator.c:14)
==10307== 
==10307== 
==10307== 268 (12 direct, 256 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 85 of 95
==10307==    at 0x40269EE: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:224)
==10307==    by 0x465072F: Dyninst::SymtabAPI::builtInTypeCollection::getAllBuiltInTypes() (Collections.C:673)
==10307==    by 0x46223C6: Dyninst::SymtabAPI::Symtab::getAllbuiltInTypes() (Symtab.C:2188)
==10307==    by 0x435E598: BPatch::BPatch() (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x804914B: main (mutator.c:14)
==10307== 
==10307== 
==10307== 144 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 91 of 95
==10307==    at 0x4025092: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:397)
==10307==    by 0x401128B: _dl_allocate_tls (in /lib/ld-2.9.so)
==10307==    by 0x4A0F672: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1 (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.9.so)
==10307==    by 0x441B852: InternalThread::createThread() (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x44543B5: BPatch_asyncEventHandler::initialize() (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x435E62A: BPatch::BPatch() (in ~/Desktop/Masters/dyninstAPI/src/i386-unknown-linux2.4/lib/libdyninstAPI.so)
==10307==    by 0x804914B: main (mutator.c:14)
==10307== 
==10307== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10307==    definitely lost: 188 bytes in 6 blocks.
==10307==    indirectly lost: 4,067 bytes in 46 blocks.
==10307==      possibly lost: 1,556 bytes in 61 blocks.
==10307==    still reachable: 10,210 bytes in 309 blocks.
==10307==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==10307== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==10307== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
```

Comment: Is the "Hello World" application one from the documentation or one you've written yourself? If it's from the docs, please provide the reference. Otherwise, please post your code.

Comment: It is my own application, but is modeled after some of their sample code.

Comment: OK, that looks quite bad! What happens if you compile with -g and then do --leak-check=full?

Comment: Yup, that looks like a memory leak to me. The BPatch constructor is allocating memory that it doesn't free. I can't see anything wrong with the way you're using it but just to be fair you might want to try running the sample app in the appendix of the docs and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind is blind to what is your code and what is a library. It is likely reporting a leak in the library.

You can see *what* leaked by running, as suggested, with `--leak-check=full`

Comment: So strange ways of managing memory wouldn't "confuse" valgrind?

Comment: Valgrind instruments the heap allocators (new/delete/malloc/free/sbrk/mmap). If you're not using one of those, you're running in undefined behavior land.